# How can I support iOS 3.0 and not iOS 3.2

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, app-store

I have set my base SDK to 3.0 but don't want my app available for iPad (3.2).

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you want to limit your audience?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

your app will be rejected if it doesn't run on the ipad.
See point 2.10 of the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/)

> iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone 3GS resolution

If you just don't want to make a dedicated iPad-Version just start with a iphone-only template.